# Can I use OnCreateView with the Activity or is only used with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-oncreateview

If OnCreateView is only for fragments, what would be for Activity?
I tried OnCreate() and I cannot make it work

In the first Override I have problems, and in the last Overide it also give me an error for the OncreateView.
I have read about OnCreate() and OnCreateView(), but I cannot find the answer.

```
private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pruebafoto, container,false);
    panoWidgetView = v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the widget and free memory.
    panoWidgetView.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
    ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
    if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
        // Cancel any task from a previous loading.
        task.cancel(true);
    }

    // pass in the name of the image to load from assets.
    VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
    viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

    // use the name of the image in the assets/ directory.
    String panoImageName = "@drawable/iglesiavr.jpg";

    // create the task passing the widget view and call execute to start.
    task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
    task.execute(this.getAssets());
    backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
}

@Override
public void onCreateView(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(savedInstanceState);
    loadPanoImage();
}
```

Comment: You should research "Activity lifecycle" ... It clearly shows what methods are loaded. Then compare with "Fragment lifecycle"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what error you get.  "I need help, it doesn't work, can you help, etc?" is not a question, so please leave them out of posts. Thanks!

Comment: Are you not aware of activity and fragment lifecycle.How can you move to development.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateView()` is called only on fragment if it is an activity you may use `onCreate()` method. for further details refer this flow diagram of lifecycles.

https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

[image: https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle]

Answer (score 1):

**onCreate():**

You can use `onCreate()` inside a Fragment, it is called after the Activity's `onAttachFragment()` but before that Fragment's `onCreateView()`.
In this method, you can assign variables, get Intent extras, and anything else that doesn't involve the View hierarchy. However, you can't use `onCreateView()` inside an Activity.

**onCreateView():**

You can assign your View variables and do any graphical initialisations. You are expected to return a root View from this method, and this is the main view, but if your Fragment does not use any layouts or graphics, you can return null.

Answer (score 0):

For an Activity, we have [`onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)
You'd need something like following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pruebafoto);  
        Log.i("lifecycle","onCreate invoked"); 
        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView ) findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        loadPanoImage(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Activities use `onCreate` only. Fragments have both.

`onCreate` uses `setContentView`, not an inflater, or `super.onCreateView`

Your error with this code is that you defined `onCreateView` **twice** and the second one (at the bottom), does not Override anything. It needs to return a View, but you have it `void`. That looks like you tried to define `onCreate`, but left it as `onCreateView`.

Delete the second, move `loadPanoImage()` to the first, before the return.

Comment: I already deleted the Override at the bottom and move the loadPanoImage() to the first Override before the return. I changed onCreateActivity for onCreate, but the Override still gives me error.

Comment: Again, Activity has no `onCreateView`, so no, there is nothing to override, and that will be an error

Comment: Override
    public View onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pruebafoto, container,false);
        panoWidgetView = v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        loadPanoImage();
        return v;
    }

Comment: Your method is named onCreate now... It must be `onCreateView`, which needs to be in a Fragment

Comment: OK, now I have an Activity and I am using OnCreate() and the panoWidgetView. Now the app builds succesfully, but when I try it in the emulator everything works fine, except it does not load the image in the PanoView (the app crashes when I go to the Activity where the Panowidget is.

Comment: @Javi Please post a new question that includes your Logcat, not a comment here. We've answered the existing error.